# Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl. Even though they are already installed

Tags: php, mysql, openssl, xampp, composer-php

When I start XAMPP's Apache and MySQL and click on the admin button of the MySQL the following error message appears:

```
    Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl
```

What's weird is that I already have mysqli and openssl installed as when type `php -m`
in the cmd the following modules appear:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

I have already searched through Stack Overflow and tried many solutions, but none have worked yet.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Are you sure that `php -m` and Composer use the same PHP configuration? Also, what kind of "admin button" do you mean? Why should MySQL itself depend on PHP?